# JAVA The method getWindowAncestor(Component) in the type SwingUtilities is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java

Есть строчка

```
JFrame topFrame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
```

Eclipse ругается

> A The method getWindowAncestor(Component) in the type SwingUtilities is not applicable for the arguments

Не пойму в чем дело, в гугле особо ничего не понял, что написано, подскажите, куда глядеть?

Answer (score 0):

возможно ваш класс унаследован не от того Component, сравните импорты в вашем классе и в SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor
или же как вариант, возможно вы случайно импортировали не те SwingUtilities